# Unexpected unknown pseudo-element selector "::ng-deep" angular 10

Tags: angular, sonarqube

I am trying to overwrite the angular 10 material so I used ::ng-deep but is getting error in sonarqube. please help me to resolve the issue.

```
:host {
::ng-deep {
.act-sale-container {
margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.mat-tab-label-container {
margin-left: 2rem;
z-index: 0
}
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar,
.mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar {
background-color: $primary-color;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-deep` is deprecated since a long time now, but there is, as much as I know, no good replacement for it yet. Either put your css code in the global css file is possible, or still use it and maybe add a rule in your SonarQube to ignore this specific case.

Also, depending on your needs, angular material expose multiples classes for you to edit their component, you'll find them in [the documentation](https://v10.material.angular.io/).

A solution to this could be to set your component to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and works with encapsulated scss. See [this answer](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160#issuecomment-504642697) from a thread about ng-deep deprecation for more detail.

If it's not enough and you put your style in a global css file, don't forget to encapsulate it with a class/id so it doesn't impact the rest of your code.